# tensor index manipulation with "..."

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

Hi I'm new to Pytorch and torch tensors. I'm reading yolo_v3 code and encounter this question. I think it relates to tensor indexing with `...`, but it's difficult to search `...` by google, so I figure to ask it here. The code is:

```
        prediction = (
            x.view(num_samples, self.num_anchors, self.num_classes + 5, grid_size, grid_size)
            .permute(0, 1, 3, 4, 2)
            .contiguous()
        )
        print (prediction.shape)
        # Get outputs
        x = torch.sigmoid(prediction[..., 0])  # Center x
        y = torch.sigmoid(prediction[..., 1])  # Center y
        w = prediction[..., 2]  # Width
        h = prediction[..., 3]  # Height
        pred_conf = torch.sigmoid(prediction[..., 4])  # Conf
        pred_cls = torch.sigmoid(prediction[..., 5:])  # Cls pred.
```

My understanding is that the prediction will be a tensor with shape of [batch, anchor, x_grid, y_grid, class]. But what does prediction[..., x] do (x=0,1,2,3,4,5)? Is it similar as numpy indexing of [:, x]? If so the calculation of x, y, w, h, pred_conf and pred_cls don't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's call [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#the-ellipsis-object). It indicate unspecified dimensions of `ndarray` or `tensor`.

Here, if `prediction` shape is `[batch, anchor, x_grid, y_grid, class]` then

```
prediction[..., 0] # is equivalent to prediction[:,:,:,:,0]
prediction[..., 1] # is equivalent to prediction[:,:,:,:,1]
```

More

```
prediction[0, ..., 0] # equivalent to prediction[0,:,:,:,0]
```

You can also write `...` as `Ellipsis`

```
prediction[Ellipsis, 0]
```